# Angular "ngif" doesn't work while getting a undefined value

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to do that if my array doesn't have some values or some values are undefined in html just don't try to get it from array.

> Empty array : [ {0: undefined} ]

Full array :

```
[
{0: "Name"},  
{1: "img.src"},  
{2: name: string,  family: string, age: number} 
]
```

0: "Name" , 1: "img.src" 2 {name: string, family: string; age: number}

My try which isn't working :

```
   <div *ngFor="let fam of familyArray" class="grid-item">
        <button ion-button>
          <img *ngIf="fam[1] != undefined && fam[1] != null "  class="selectImg" src="{{fam[1]}}" alt="">
        </button>
        <span *ngIf="fam[2].name != undefined && family[2].age != undefined  && family[2].age != null && family[2].name != null " class="image-text">{{fam[2].name}}, {{family[2].age}}m.</span>
        <p *ngIf="fam[2].family != undefined  && fam[2].family != null "  class="family-status">{{fam[2].family}}</p>
      </div>
```

I always get this errors :

> TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

or

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: what is Full array?

Comment: Empty array if nothing is added and full array is an example of full one object array. There can be multiple objects with these 3 objects.

Comment: it's ok. Are Name and Example variables?

Comment: 0: "Name" , 1: "img.src" 2 {name: string, family: string; age: number}

Comment: can you seperately add what are the possbiel inputs of familyArray which helps in debugging

Comment: edited post,  where u see " " there is string in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to put checks for undefined and null, It take cares it self for undefined and nulls, you just need to specify like below:

```
      <div *ngFor="let fam of familyArray" class="grid-item" >
        <button *ngIf="fam[0]" ion-button>
          <img *ngIf="fam[1]"  class="selectImg" src="{{fam[1]}}" alt="">
        </button>
        <span *ngIf="fam[2] && fam[2].name && family[2].age" class="image-text">{{fam[2].name}}, {{family[2].age}}m.</span>
        <p *ngIf="fam[2].family"  class="family-status">{{fam[2].family}}</p>
      </div>
```

The array of object which you are receiving is actually a wrong format, all the object should be in same types and some standard conventions need to be followed though.

Answer (score 2):

```
   <div *ngFor="let fam of familyArray" class="grid-item">
    <button ion-button>
      <img *ngIf="fam['1'] != undefined && fam['1'] != null "  class="selectImg" src="{{fam['1']}}" alt="">
    </button>
    <span *ngIf="fam['2'].name != undefined && family['2'].age != undefined  && family['2'].age != null && family['2'].name != null " class="image-text">{{fam['2'].name}}, {{family['2'].age}}m.</span>
    <p *ngIf="fam['2'].family != undefined  && fam['2'].family != null "  class="family-status">{{fam['2'].family}}</p>
  </div>
```

Above code 3 times as there are 3 objects in your array.
First time value of fam is `{0: Name},`
Second time `{1: img.src},`
and third time `{2: name: Example,  family: example, age:15}`

there is not such object fam[1]
I hope I have explained enough.

Comment: this is what ? a solution or what ? This isn't helping. Because as you can see I made ngIf with checking if it's null or undefined.

Comment: so you should try <img *ngIf="fam['1'] != undefined && fam['1'] != null "  class="selectImg" src="{{fam['1']}}" alt="">

Comment: This has the answer

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by doing this :

HTML (**added ngIf to the button**) :

```
   <div *ngFor="let fam of familyArray" class="grid-item" >
        <button *ngIf="familyArray[0] != undefined " ion-button>
          <img *ngIf="fam[1] != undefined && fam[1] != null "  class="selectImg" src="{{fam[1]}}" alt="">
        </button>
        <span *ngIf="fam[2].name != undefined && family[2].age != undefined  && family[2].age != null && family[2].name != null " class="image-text">{{fam[2].name}}, {{family[2].age}}m.</span>
        <p *ngIf="fam[2].family != undefined  && fam[2].family != null "  class="family-status">{{fam[2].family}}</p>
      </div>
```

**And made that my array would be empty, not 0:undefined if nothing is there.**

Answer (score 0):

You had added the additional checks for undefined and null and missed the check in couple of places.

Here is the working copy of your example - 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e8zjsq

Answer (score 0):

```
`  <div class="count-section" fxLayout="row">
                    <span fxFlex="13.3%" >Super cell: <b>{{countAnalysisDrugInfo[2].value}}</b></span>
                    <span fxFlex="12.3%" >Locking cell: <b>{{countAnalysisDrugInfo[0].value}}</b></span>
                    <span fxFlex="12.3%" >Regular cell: <b *ngIf="countAnalysisDrugInfo[4]">{{countAnalysisDrugInfo[4].value}}</b></span>
                    <span fxFlex="16.3%" >Super locking cell: <b>{{countAnalysisDrugInfo[3].value}}</b></span>
                    <span fxFlex="12.3%" >Schedule ll: <b>{{countAnalysisDrugInfo[0].value}}</b></span>
                    <span fxFlex="12.3%" >Schedule lll: <b>{{countAnalysisDrugInfo[1].value}}</b></span>
                </div>`
```